# Random Godot beginner-question: en-/disable CheckButton

Tags: button, input, godot

how can I enable or disable a CheckButton via code? Is there any simple way like "input pickable true/false" I use with collision shapes? I played around with control focus modes but didn't succeed.

For example: I'd like to have a timer starting when button down / holding down and after a certain time the button shouldn't react at release anymore. Just as if it was never put down in the first place...

There must be a simple command for that, right?

Edit:

Trying

*my_button.disabled = true*

leads to the error

*Invalid set index 'disabled' (on base: 'GDScriptNativeClass') with value of type 'bool'*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the `pressed` property.

```
my_button.pressed = true
```

The documentation isn't very clear on the usage but it does what you're describing. https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_checkbutton.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It appears that simply disabled = true or false also works with CheckButton.
A beginner like me can read through some of these docs several times and still not understand, ah well... it'll come I guess!